# Rollover Fade In Throwing Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to create a rollover text display gadget. When the user hovers over the picture, the picture fades (opacity is turned down) then a text appears. When the user hovers out of the picture, it toggles back to normal (pciture has opacity=1, text is gone).

I tested my early version of this and when hovering the picture, I did not see any text appear. I ran through the debugger and got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'display'
```

I have duplicated my small project in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parion/bzf6L/). If anybody could help my text appear and remove the error, it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `display` does not exist. What do you want to achieve with this method?

Comment: I thought "span" had a default method for display in Jquery??

Comment: I believe on hover he want's to fade the images opacity and display his text over the image.  He currently has the text set to display:none and is looking for a way to set display:block, or somehting along those lines.

Comment: @parion You are probably talking about [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) , or [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use CSS3 transitions to get a similar effect: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/bzf6L/1/

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
}
img:hover {
    opacity : .2;
}
span {
    font-family:Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.hovertext {
    position: aboslute;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Two Questions: 1. Curios, what is the -webkit css properties? I've read up on CSS but I've never seen these. 2. I'm trying to center the text using this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/. Is there a way to center the text onto the image using the image as the parent and not the document?

Comment: 1. Web-kits are for newer browsers.  In this example, it is used to achieve the fade in fade out effect. 2. See if this works http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/bzf6L/2/

Comment: Thanks man! Got plenty to look up about webkits and other CSS properties. Take care!

Comment: @parion Correction: `-webkit-` will affect all browsers developped with the [WebKit](https://www.webkit.org/) (this includes Chromium, Chrome, Safari, Canary to say the least). `-o-` is for Opera, `-moz-` is for mozilla (gecko) browsers and `-ms-` is for latest versions of Microsoft's Internet Explorer.

Comment: So why do you specify transition for all the browsers and not just use only transition: all...

Comment: webkits are specific to the browsers specified.  For instance, if you leave out -moz-transition:, firefox will not have the transition effect but the other browswers will.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. jQuery doesn't have a function called `display`
2. In your fiddle, the `.hovertext` span is not a child of `.pic`, so `$('.hovertext', $(this))`, where `$(this)` is one of the images, won't select anything.

Comment: 1. I'm pretty new to JQuery. Does it have a toggle method for Opacity?

2. So do I throw the <span> tag inside the image tags?

Comment: @parion the jquery documentation is a great place to learn. Here's a search for opacity: http://api.jquery.com/?s=opacity (I would check <strike>fadeToggle</strike> fadeTo first)

Comment: FYI - In this particular instance, I agree with dwreck08 that css3 transitions are probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.fadeTo()` instead of `.slideToggle()` It will toggle itself because of the `onhover` state:

### JavaScript

```js
$('.pic').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(9);
    //here is the place for the function to show the text.
});
```